# Gallery with thumbs, too many foreach loops (?) (PHP)

Tags: php, loops, foreach, gallery, thumbnails

I have a problem with agallery in PHP. The gallery has the following construction:

```
            <div class="imageElement">
                <h3>Item 1 Title</h3>
                <p>Item 1 Description</p>
                <a href="open/1.jpg" title="open image" class="open"></a>
                <img src="big/1-gallery.jpg" class="full" />
                <img src="thumb/1-mini.jpg" class="thumbnail" />
            </div>
      and so on
```

I have three folders: 
big - with normal images, 
thumb - with thumbs, 
open - with large images.

I have created a foreach loop:

```
<?php foreach(glob("images/folder/images/".$id."/big/*.jpg") as $filename) : ?>

<div class="imageElement">
<h3>Item 1 Title</h3>
<p>Item 1 Description</p>
<a href="path-to-large-image" title="open image" class="open"></a>
<? echo '<img src="'.$filename.'" class="full">'?>

<?php foreach(glob("images/folder/images/".$id."/thumb/*.jpg") as $filename2) : ?    >
<? echo '<img src="'.$filename2.'" class="thumbnail">';break;?>
 <?php endforeach ?>
</div>
<?php endforeach ?>
```

Unfortunately I got only the first - the same thumb to every image. How should I use foreach loop in such case? How should I use next loop to get image from open folder?

Thanks for answers.

Edit:

My output in html looks:

```
<div class="imageElement">
<h3>title</h3>
<p>text</p>
<a href="/images/folder/4/open/1.jpg" title="open image" class="open"></a>
<a href="/images/folder/4/open/2.jpg" title="open image" class="open"></a>
<a href="/images/folder/4/open/3.jpg" title="open image" class="open"></a>
<a href="/images/folder/4/open/4.jpg" title="open image" class="open"></a>

<img src="images/folder/images/4/big/1.jpg" class="full">

<img src="/images/folder/images/4/thumb/1.jpg" class="thumbnail">
<img src="/images/folder/images/4/thumb/2.jpg" class="thumbnail">
<img src="/images/folder/images/4/thumb/3.jpg" class="thumbnail">
<img src="/images/folder/images/4/thumb/4.jpg" class="thumbnail">
</div>

<div class="imageElement">
<h3>title</h3>
<p>text</p>
<a href="/images/folder/4/open/1.jpg" title="open image" class="open"></a>
<a href="/images/folder/4/open/2.jpg" title="open image" class="open"></a>
<a href="/images/folder/4/open/3.jpg" title="open image" class="open"></a>
<a href="/images/folder/4/open/4.jpg" title="open image" class="open"></a>

<img src="images/folder/images/4/big/2.jpg" class="full">

<img src="/images/folder/images/4/thumb/1.jpg" class="thumbnail">
<img src="/images/folder/images/4/thumb/2.jpg" class="thumbnail">
<img src="/images/folder/images/4/thumb/3.jpg" class="thumbnail">
<img src="/images/folder/images/4/thumb/4.jpg" class="thumbnail">
</div>
```

and so on.

It should look:

```
<div class="imageElement">
<h3>title</h3>
<p>text</p>
<a href="/images/folder/4/open/1.jpg" title="open image" class="open"></a>
<img src="images/folder/images/4/big/1.jpg" class="full">
<img src="/images/folder/images/4/thumb/1.jpg" class="thumbnail">
</div>

<div class="imageElement">
<h3>title</h3>
<p>text</p>
<a href="/images/folder/4/open/2.jpg" title="open image" class="open"></a>
<img src="images/folder/images/4/big/2.jpg" class="full">
<img src="/images/folder/images/4/thumb/2.jpg" class="thumbnail">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The way you constructed your code, mixing PHP and HTML, could confuse PHP. Try this:

```
<?php
foreach(glob("images/folder/images/".$id."/big/*.jpg") as $filename) {

  echo '<div class="imageElement">
<h3>Item 1 Title</h3>
<p>Item 1 Description</p>
<a href="path-to-large-image" title="open image" class="open"></a>
<img src="'.$filename.'" class="full">';

  foreach(glob("images/folder/images/".$id."/thumb/*.jpg") as $filename2) {
    echo '<img src="'.$filename2.'" class="thumbnail">';
  }
  echo '</div>';
}
```

EDIT:

This produces what you are looking for:

```
foreach($x as $filename) {
  $chunks=explode("/", $filename);
  $file=$chunks[count($chunks)-1];

  echo '<div class="imageElement">
  <h3>Item 1 Title</h3>
  <p>Item 1 Description</p>
  <a href="./images/folder/images/'.$id.'/open/'.$file.'" title="open image" class="open"></a>
  <img src="./images/folder/images/'.$id.'/big/'.$file.'" class="full">
  <img src="./images/folder/images/'.$id.'/thumb/'.$file.'" class="thumbnail">

  </div>


  ';

}
```

Output:

```
<div class="imageElement">
<h3>Item 1 Title</h3>
<p>Item 1 Description</p>
<a href="./images/folder/images/4/open/1.jpg" title="open image" class="open"></a>
<img src="./images/folder/images/4/big/1.jpg" class="full">
<img src="./images/folder/images/4/thumb/1.jpg" class="thumbnail">

</div>


<div class="imageElement">
<h3>Item 1 Title</h3>
<p>Item 1 Description</p>
<a href="./images/folder/images/4/open/2.jpg" title="open image" class="open"></a>
<img src="./images/folder/images/4/big/2.jpg" class="full">
<img src="./images/folder/images/4/thumb/2.jpg" class="thumbnail">

</div>


<div class="imageElement">
<h3>Item 1 Title</h3>
<p>Item 1 Description</p>
<a href="./images/folder/images/4/open/3.jpg" title="open image" class="open"></a>
<img src="./images/folder/images/4/big/3.jpg" class="full">
<img src="./images/folder/images/4/thumb/3.jpg" class="thumbnail">

</div>


<div class="imageElement">
<h3>Item 1 Title</h3>
<p>Item 1 Description</p>
<a href="./images/folder/images/4/open/4.jpg" title="open image" class="open"></a>
<img src="./images/folder/images/4/big/4.jpg" class="full">
<img src="./images/folder/images/4/thumb/4.jpg" class="thumbnail">

</div>
```

Only thing to fix is the Item 1 Title/Description.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have tried in such a way but then nothing displays.

Comment: You might want to try and have a look at what glob() returns. As a test, try `print_r(glob("images/folder/images/".$id."/big/*.jpg"));` inside the loop, instead of the real code, see what gets printed out.

Comment: Thanks. I got array with four elements (4 pictures). I know that there is something wrong with loops. I have foreach loop for normal pictures, for thumbs and I would like to use loop to get large pictures from another folder. When I see output in html I got... I will update my first post.